# How do I create a reusable function to remove rows based on values in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the code bellow to remove rows that contain the strings in "listToRemove" from the colours column. This works, removing the rows I want and leaving the rest. I am having trouble creating a function that can be reused to remove rows in the same way for other datasets.

```
df = raw_data

listToRemove = ["red", "blue"]

raw_data = raw_data[raw_data.colours.isin(list1) == False]
```

I have come up with this function. This does not work. How do I create a function to remove rows based on values in a specific column?

```
def removeRows( df, column, [list]):
    listToRemove = [list]
    df = df[df.column.isin(listToRemove) == False]
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes:

```
def remove_rows(df, column, values_to_remove):
    return df[~df[column].isin(values_to_remove)]
```

BTW try to use variable names in `snake_case`

Comment: This seems logical. How would you input the arguments for values_to_remove for my case mentioned above?

Comment: I guess: 

df = raw_data

listToRemove = ["red", "blue"]

new_df = remove_rows(df, "your_column", listToRemove)

Answer (score 1):

For adding listToRemove function to be performed you should load the data present in document of type(csv or any other) read through pandas as dataframe and then apply this one.

Try this:

```
def removeRows(df, column, listToRemove):
df = df[df[column].isin(list_to_remove)]
return df
```